# c# button 2 can only be click after button 1 clicked

Tags: c#, .net

I am really new to C# and visual studio

My situation here is I have 2 button where `button1_click` (to do some processing) and `button2_click` (to go to next process)

What i want to ask, is it possible to do something like, to set `button2_click` can only be clicked only after the user click the `button1_click` at first..

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set button2 enabled property to false. 
And in button1_click event handler set button2 enabled property to true.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible, to do this you have to disable the `Button2` initially and then enable that inside the Click event of `Button1`; Something like the following:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if("some condition if needed")
   {
       Button2.Enabled = true;
   }
}
```

Make sure that `Button2` is disabled initially or else include this `Button2.Enabled = false;` in the page/form load